# Finding a table item with a variable?

Tags: lua

So, i made a script with a rather large table be warned,

```
mod = {
 {"1", "a"},
{"2", "i"},
{"3", "u"},
{"4", "e"},
{"5", "o"},
{"6", "ka"},
{"7", "ki"},
{"8", "ku"},
{"9", "ke"},
{"10", "ko"},
{"11", "sa"},
{"12", "shi"},
{"13", "su"},
{"14", "se"},
{"15", "so"},
{"16", "ta"},
{"17", "chi"},
{"18", "tsu"},
{"19", "te"},
{"20", "to"},
{"21", "na"},
{"22", "ni"},
{"23", "nu"},
{"24", "ne"},
{"25", "no"},
{"26", "ha"},
{"27", "hi"},
{"28", "fu"},
{"29", "he"},
{"30", "ho"},
{"31", "ma"},
{"32", "mi"},
{"33", "mu"},
{"34", "me"},
{"35", "mo"},
{"36", "ya"},
{"37", "yu"},
{"38", "yo"},
{"39", "ra"},
{"40", "ri"},
{"41", "ru"},
{"42", "re"},
{"43", "ro"},
{"44", "wa"},
{"45", "wo"},
{"46", "n"},
{"47", "ga"},
{"48", "gi"},
{"49", "gu"},
{"50", "ge"},
{"51", "go"},
{"52", "za"},
{"53", "ji"},
{"54", "zu"},
{"55", "ze"},
{"56", "zo"},
{"57", "da"},
{"58", "ji"},
{"59", "zu"},
{"60", "de"},
{"61", "do"},
{"62", "ba"},
{"63", "bi"},
{"64", "bu"},
{"65", "be"},
{"66", "bo"},
{"67", "pa"},
{"68", "pi"},
{"69", "pu"},
{"70", "pe"},
{"71", "po"},
{"72", "kya"},
{"73", "kyu"},
{"74", "kyo"},
{"75", "gya"},
{"76", "gyu"},
{"77", "gyo"},
{"78", "sha"},
{"79", "shu"},
{"80", "sho"},
{"81", "jya"},
{"82", "jyu"},
{"83", "jyo"},
{"84", "cha"},
{"85", "chu"},
{"86", "cho"},
{"87", "nya"},
{"88", "nyu"},
{"89", "nyo"},
{"90", "hya"},
{"91", "hyu"},
{"92", "hyo"},
{"93", "bya"},
{"94", "byu"},
{"95", "byo"},
{"96", "pya"},
{"97", "pyu"},
{"98", "pyo"},
{"99", "mya"},
{"100", "myu"},
{"101", "myo"},
{"102", "rya"},
{"103", "ryu"},
{"104", "ryo"},
}

local str = ""
local RN = 0
local c = 0
local NL = 5
repeat
    RN = 13 --
for i,v in ipairs(mod) do
  if v[1] == RN then ------ here
    local RL = v[2]
    str = str.. RL
    print(str)
    c = c + 1
  end
end

until c == NL
```

and i was having issues with the line i have marked, I am attempting to retreive the 13th item in the table, ("su") and if i were to type 13 instead of RN (which has a value of 13) it would work but it doesnt using this variable. How do i do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or an alternative to what Ivo says could be just convert it to number in order to make it work. E.g., using this instead...

```
  if tonumber(v[1]) == RN then ------ here
```

...should work (or you could have used simply numbers in your table instead strings, unless it's non convenient for whatever reason, of course).

**EDIT**: And here the code snippet so that you can try:

```html
<script src="//github.com/fengari-lua/fengari-web/releases/download/v0.1.4/fengari-web.js"></script>
<script type="application/lua">

mod = {
    {"1", "a"},
    {"2", "i"},
    {"3", "u"},
    {"4", "e"},
    {"5", "o"},
    {"6", "ka"},
    {"7", "ki"},
    {"8", "ku"},
    {"9", "ke"},
    {"10", "ko"},
    {"11", "sa"},
    {"12", "shi"},
    {"13", "su"},
    {"14", "se"},
    {"15", "so"},
    {"16", "ta"},
    }

local str = ""
local RN = 0
local c = 0
local NL = 5
repeat
    RN = 13 --
    for i, v in ipairs(mod) do
        if tonumber(v[1]) == RN then ------ here
            local RL = v[2]
            str = str .. RL
            print(str)
            c = c + 1
        end
    end
until c == NL

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing numbers with strings. Change

```
RN = 13
```

to

```
RN = "13"
```